# How to Use the Super-User Password to Log Into Any User Account

Tags: joomla

I'm developing a new Joomla 3 website. The old Joomla 2.5 website enabled Super Users to log into any user account from the frontend using only the user's username and the super-admin password. This enabled Joomla super administrators of the site to access any user account without knowing that user's password. So basically, if the site administrator wanted to log into any user account, all they need is that user's username.

My question is, is there a feature or a Joomla plugin in Joomla 3 that allows this?

Comment: This is a question about Joomla and Joomla administration. Please use http://joomla.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Joomla 2.5 didn't allow this by default (also Joomla 1.5 for that matter). I think you were using an extension on your old Joomla 2.5 website that handled such authentication but you didn't know that you had it installed.

In any case, we have created an extension that does exactly what you want (it's a plugin actually) and it's available for download here: http://www.itoctopus.com/super-login-a-free-joomla-plugin-that-allows-a-super-user-to-login-as-any-user

The plugin is compatible with Joomla 3.x (last tested on Joomla 3.4.5 ). It is also free and doesn't come with any "hidden links".

Comment: Thanks @Itoctopus, the old joomla 2.5 was created by someone else so I couldn't tell whether it was a plugin but your plugin seem to be example what I'm looking for. I can't tell you how many months I tried researching on this. I should have posted my question on stackoverflow sooner. Thanks